# Creating a procedure to fetch details from diff tables and fill them in a custom table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a custom table ctable(varchar,varchar,date,number) and fill the details by fetching from other tables and a custom view.The two varchars are from one table and a view and date and number from other table.

Date has to be today's date.

How can I write a procedure to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I'd do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE POPULATE_CTABLE AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CTABLE (VARCHAR_FIELD_1, VARCHAR_FIELD_2, DATE_FIELD, NUMBER_FIELD)
    -- put your SELECT which grabs the fields you want here

END POPULATE_CUSTOM_TABLE;
```

Without knowing the real names of the fields, the name of the view and "other" table(s), and how the various views and tables are related it's difficult to be more specific than this.

Best of luck.

Comment: varchar_1 from CIFDATA 
varchar_2 from GAM 
date,number from DTD based on the input date
How can I write multiple select to single insert?